# "LNK2019: Unresolved External Symbol" error with glew/glut

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, shared-ptr, lnk2019

I am not the best yet at OOP practices and that is what is contributing to this bug but I am really needing your help on this. I have a handful of files in here but I will try and post only the relevant pieces.

**PLY.cpp:**

```
#include "PLY.hpp"

std::vector<Point> m_VBO;
std::vector<GLuint> m_IBO;
std::shared_ptr<cs5400::Program> program;
GLint attribute_coord3d;
GLuint m_glPoints;

void onDisplay()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(program->getHandle());
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord3d);
    std::vector<GLfloat> floats;
    GLfloat* triangle_verts = floats.data();

    glVertexAttribPointer(
        attribute_coord3d,
        3,
        GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE,
        0,
        triangle_verts
        );

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(attribute_coord3d);

    glutSwapBuffers();
 }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    returnDataFromFile("bun_zipper.ply", m_VBO, m_IBO);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("PLY Importer");

    GLenum glew_status = glewInit();
    if(glew_status != GLEW_OK)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try
    {
        program = cs5400::make_program  //This is the function I'm getting my error on
            (
            cs5400::make_vertexShader("vertex.glsl"), 
            cs5400::make_fragmentShader("fragment.glsl")
            );
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay);
        //glutIdleFunc(onIdle);
        //glutKeyboardFunc(onKey);
        glutMainLoop();
    }
    catch(std::exception e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

**Ply.h** includes the **Program.hpp** and the **Program.cpp** looks like:

```
#include "Program.hpp"

std::shared_ptr<cs5400::Program> cs5400::make_program
(
  std::shared_ptr<cs5400::VertexShader> vertex
 ,std::shared_ptr<cs5400::FragmentShader> fragment  
)
{
  GLint link_ok = GL_FALSE;
  auto program = std::make_shared<Program>(vertex,fragment);
  glAttachShader(program->getHandle(), vertex->getHandle());
  glAttachShader(program->getHandle(), fragment->getHandle());
  glLinkProgram(program->getHandle());
  glGetProgramiv(program->getHandle(), GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_ok);
  if (!link_ok) 
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not link shader program.");
  }
  return program;
}
```

However when compiling I get a `LNK2019` error for my `std::shared_ptr<cs5400::Program>` piece of my main function in `PLY.cpp`. All the includes are correct as far as I know and I don't know what else to do. Anyone have any experience with Linker errors?

Here is the complete error:

```
1> PLY.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class cs5400::Program> __cdecl cs5400::make_program(class std::shared_ptr<class cs5400::Shader<struct cs5400::detail::VertexShaderTag> >,class std::shared_ptr<class cs5400::Shader<struct cs5400::detail::FragmentShaderTag> >)" (?make_program@cs5400@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VProgram@cs5400@@@std@@V?$shared_ptr@V?$Shader@UVertexShaderTag@detail@cs5400@@@cs5400@@@3@V?$shared_ptr@V?$Shader@UFragmentShaderTag@detail@cs5400@@@cs5400@@@3@@Z) referenced in function _main
1> C:\Users\Brenton\Documents\School\Visual Studio 2012\PLY\Debug\PLY.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: OK, so the linker is not finding `cs5400::make_program()`. Can you show us how this function is declared? Also, are you sure `Program.cpp`, where `cs5400::make_program()` is defined is being compiled? Is that file indeed part of the VS project?